# Is there any way to type the symbol for the Mac CMD key?

Tags: mac, keyboard, special-characters

I would like to be able to use the symbol for CMD in a document, without requiring an image. Obviously, if the display font doesn't support it there'll be a problem, but given that it's in a document that will only ever be shown on a mac it should be fine ... if it's possible at all.

Is it?  If so, how?

Comment: copy and paste me: ⌘

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options that I can think of:

1. Go to the Wikipedia article and copy and paste the character.
2. **Initial Setup:** Enable the Unicode Hex Input as a keyboard in System Preferences => Language and Text => Input Sources. Also check "Show Input menu in menu bar". **To type character:** Select Unicode Hex Input from the keyboard selector in the menu bar. Type 2318, the Unicode character code, while holding down the Alt key.

Answer (score 2):

Set the font to wingdings and press the 'z' key

Answer (score 0):

In System Preferences > Keyboard, check "Show Keyboard & Character Viewer in menu bar". Then select the Character Viewer, click in the "Description & code" field, start typing "PLACE OF INTEREST SIGN", and when it shows up, select it. You can add it to your Favorites here in Character Viewer so you can more easily select/enter it in the future.